# How to optimise this regex to split line on spaces and punctuation marks (minus apostrophes)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a text line on spaces and punctuation marks, which I've managed to done, but it's also now containing empty spaces in the resulting split line array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "tim's work 'cool' asdas 'right' three-year-old 123123.";
        String rePattern = "[?,.!\\s]|(?<=\\s)\\'|\\'(?=[^a-zA-Z])";

        String[] arr = test.split(rePattern);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

For example, the above spit will print:

```
tim's
work

cool

asdas

right
```

So it looks like I'm managing to split on punctuation marks properly, but it's still including empty strings in the array. How can I optimise my regex so it doesn't include empty strings when it splits?

Comment: Is "was" missing in the result?

Comment: @RobertBain woops my bad i must've added in 'was' in the test string to make myself look less illterate :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to surround the space/sentence-terminating character set with optional `'`s on each side, ensuring that `'`s get consumed by the `split` *along with* the space/sentence terminators, when possible:

```
String rePattern = "'?[?,.!\\s]'?";
```

Output:

```
tim's
work
was
cool
asdas
right
```

Do note that there's no need to escape `'`s in regular expressions, at least not in Java where the string delimiters are `"`. Additionally, unless you're expecting spaces *other* than plain spaces that you would want to split on (for example, a newline, or a tab character, or something like that), you can just use a literal space rather than `\\s`, if you like, it's more precise and concise (eg `String rePattern = "'?[?,.! ]'?";` )

Comment: Nice, but doesn't answer his question. It still results in empty elements as a result. And since you've fundamentally altered his quote  construct, it doesn't work the same. So, it is the wrong answer. https://regex101.com/r/Bu711z/1

Comment: I did test it first, it doesn't result in empty elements? The refactored regex achieves his desired output, but is much cleaner (OP probably would have said something if this didn't work and there was some other particular logic he was looking for)

Comment: If you click that link in my comment you see 14 matches but there should be only 7 split points,  and as said you've fundamentally altered the quote constructs which is not the same as intended. And how would the person who asked the question know this ? See my edit below for the solution.

Comment: OP didn't give any indication that his input text could be that strange. It's not hard to solve (maybe something like `(?:\B'|'\B|[?,.!\s])+`), but it's not what OP was asking for. If it was actually a problem, surely OP would have said something before accepting

Answer (score 1):

Since you have overlapping delimiters you need to combine into a more than 1 match.

`"(?:[?,.!\\s]|(?<=\\s)'|'(?=[^a-zA-Z]))+"`

https://regex101.com/r/BRYxiE/1

```
 (?:
      [?,.!\s] 
   |  
      (?<= \s )
      '
   |  
      '
      (?= [^a-zA-Z] )
 )+
```

It actually may be better to *match* what you want instead of splitting.
You'd get better control.

**edit:**
After a quick review of the edge cases, it is determined that
this construct `(?<=\s)` is a positive requirement that should be replaced with this `(?<!\S)` a negative requirement, a whitespace boundary.

The reason is that a whitespace or negative boundary also match at BOS/EOS.

The revised regex is then

`"(?:[?,.!\\s]|(?<!\\S)'|'(?=[^a-zA-Z]))+"`

https://regex101.com/r/JGQ6Rw/1

```
 (?:
      [?,.!\s] 
   |  
      (?<! \S )
      '
   |  
      '
      (?= [^a-zA-Z] )
 )+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposed new solution.
Instead of worrying about particular punctuation, split on all punctuation
not surrounded by `[a-z]` letter.

`"(?i)(?:(?:\\pP+|\\s)(?<![a-z]\\pP(?=[a-z])))+"`

https://regex101.com/r/cNmHF8/1

```
 (?i)
 (?:
      (?: \pP+ | \s )               # Punct's or whitespace
      (?<!                          # But not under both these conditions
           [a-z] \pP                     # A letter directly before Punct
           (?= [a-z] )                   # and a letter directly after
      )
 )+
```

This still is not the proper way to parse words.

---

***update***
`What is the proper way to parse words then..? – doctopus`

Well, if it's controlled by punctuation only, the best way imo
is to recognize the internal parts of a word.

That is the beginning character, then the word body.
The word body *can* contain punctuation as long as the possible
multiple sequence of punctuation is surrounded a letter.

Doing it this way, it cannot be done with the split function,
but has to be done with a find all type function extracting
the single capture group to get the word.

Here's how it should be done imo.

There is a special feature that allows you to enter *word ending punctuation*
that will *halt* the match and see it as the end of word.
This is needed in the case of characters like `?.!`.
Add more if needed as you see fit.

`"[^\\pL\\pN]*([\\pL\\pN](?:[\\pL\\pN_-]|(?![?.!])\\pP(?=[\\pL\\pN\\pP]))*)(?<!\\pP)"`

https://regex101.com/r/flUmcB/1

Some explanation

```
 # Unicode
 # [^\pL\pN]*([\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|(?![?.!])\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP]))*)(?<!\pP)

 [^\pL\pN]*                    # Strip non-letters/numbers               
 (                             # (1 start)
      [\pL\pN]                      # First letter/number
      (?:                           # Word body
           [\pL\pN_-]                    # Letter/number or '-'
        |                              # or,
           (?! [?.!] )                   # ( Not Special word ending punctuation, Add more here )
           \pP                           # Punctuation
           (?= [\pL\pN\pP] )             #   if followed by punctuation/letter/number
      )*                            # Do many times
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?<! \pP )                    # Don't end on a punctuation
```

Comment: What is the proper way to parse words then..?

Comment: @doctopus - Added a demonstration in the answer. Good Luck!